# DFS and BFS cycle checking

Tags: algorithm

DFS and BFS aren't terribly complicated concepts, but I find so many of the online examples to be wrong, specifically in checking for cycles. For example most pseudocode and code examples either store all the nodes in an array and use a second array to track visited, or they store all the nodes in some unique iterable container and place a 'visited' variable within the node itself, then initialize that 'visited' variable by iterating the unique container.

Those are false scenarios.

If you are just passed a graph (and maybe a start node), and no unique iterable container for setting some 'visited' node, and you have no idea how many unique nodes are in the tree, what is a good method for determining if you've visited a node already?

I can think of two: if you are guaranteed the values in the nodes are unique you can hash the value; otherwise I imagine you could hash the address of each node. The hashes would map to a 'visited' value.

Any other ideas?

Comment: Those are not false scenarios. They are the more common scenarios, and yours is the exception with its additional restrictions. The address in memory would always be unique, and as such, you could use that, but how are you going to handle hash collisions?

Comment: "store all the nodes in an array and use a second array to track visited", why this is false scenario? And maybe you should provide some link / codes you mentioned which is wrong?

Comment: I would just use an array represent the nodes, and index as their unique id, and another array for representing visited or not.  Still, this can be implemented by passing a "start" node merely. And what's wrong with this?